# Set image source to null when the image isn't visible

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

I show an image in my app. I set the source of the image from C# code.

First I set the visibility of the image:

```
<Setter TargetName="IncludeIcon" Property="Visibility" Value="{Binding Path=Clicked, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
```

Then I set the source:

```
<Setter TargetName="IncludeIcon" Property="Source" Value="{Binding MyImageSource}"></Setter>
```

The problem I have is this - when Clicked is false, I don't want the image to be shown. This works fine, but here's what I have in Visual Studio's Output tab:

```
    System.Windows.Data Error: 6 : 'TargetDefaultValueConverter' converter failed to convert value '' (type 'String'); fallback value will be used, if available. BindingExpression:Path=MyImageSource; DataItem='MyModel' (HashCode=62805747); target element is 'Image' (Name=''); target property is 'Source' (type 'ImageSource') NotSupportedException:'System.NotSupportedException: ImageSourceConverter cannot convert from System.String.
   at MS.Internal.Data.DefaultValueConverter.ConvertHelper(Object o, Type destinationType, DependencyObject targetElement, CultureInfo culture, Boolean isForward)
   at MS.Internal.Data.TargetDefaultValueConverter.Convert(Object o, Type type, Object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.ConvertHelper(IValueConverter converter, Object value, Type targetType, Object parameter, CultureInfo culture)'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error could just be coming before the property has its data bound value. Changing the `Visibility` property wouldn't produce it. Try this:

```
<Setter TargetName="IncludeIcon" Property="Source" Value="{Binding MyImageSource, 
    IsAsync=True}" />
```